# how to Change style dynamically in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to write below code with `<%=%>` sign . Here Background color is coming from service and I have to put this in server variable like below code . But its giving warning and not working properly .
Please help

```
style="background-color:<%=servicecall.color%>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the service call, before the page is rendered in the asp.net view engine and server send it back to the client. That being said, I would make the call in my serve side code, I would store the result in a variable of the corresponding page class and I would bind this value to the background-color, like

```
 style="background-color:<%=color%>"
```